# Unzip files with and without pointers

Tags: go

I'm wondering what is the right approach regarding the allocation and implementation of `ZIP` file `extraction` given the following code I wrote.

This issue is that when I'm trying to avoid using pointers when returning form `extractFiles` function in the next round the `zipStruct` struct override.
And when I'm using pointers I have to use these three:

```
clusterSetupZip[name].Pfx = append(clusterSetupZip[name].Pfx, zipStruct.Pfx...)
clusterSetupZip[name].Cert = append(clusterSetupZip[name].Cert, zipStruct.Cert...)
clusterSetupZip[name].Key = append(clusterSetupZip[name].Key, zipStruct.Key...)
```

to overcome the issue of doing it through `loop`.
What is the right `GOish` approach?

This is how the `ZIP` file is structured:

```
example.Cluster.Settings (2)
 ┣ A
 ┃ ┣ cluster.server.certificate.example.pfx
 ┃ ┗ settings.json
 ┣ B
 ┃ ┣ cluster.server.certificate.example.pfx
 ┃ ┗ settings.json
 ┣ C
 ┃ ┣ cluster.server.certificate.example.pfx
 ┃ ┗ settings.json
 ┣ admin.client.certificate.example.crt
 ┣ admin.client.certificate.example.key
 ┣ admin.client.certificate.example.pfx
 ┣ license.json
 ┣ readme.txt
 ┗ setup.json
```

This is the code:

```
func main() {
    var sc ServerConfig
    certHolderMap, err := OpenZipFile(sc, "D:\\example.Cluster.Settings.zip")
    if err != nil {
        print(err)
    }
    print(certHolderMap)
}

type ServerConfig struct {
    SetupZipPackage map[string]CertificateHolder `json:"SetupZipPackage,omitempty"`
}

type CertificateHolder struct {
    Pfx  []byte `json:"Pfx,omitempty"`
    Cert []byte `json:"Cert,omitempty"`
    Key  []byte `json:"Key,omitempty"`
}

func OpenZipFile(sc ServerConfig, path string) (map[string]CertificateHolder, error) {
    var split []string
    var zipStruct *CertificateHolder

    archive, err := zip.OpenReader(path)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    defer archive.Close()

    var clusterSetupZip = make(map[string]CertificateHolder, 3)

    for _, file := range archive.File {
        split = strings.Split(file.Name, "/")
        var name string
        if len(split) == 1 {
            name = CREDENTIALS_FOR_SECURE_STORE_FIELD_NAME
        } else {
            name = split[0]
        }

        if _, found := clusterSetupZip[name]; !found {
            clusterSetupZip[name] = CertificateHolder{
                Pfx:  make([]byte, 0),
                Cert: make([]byte, 0),
                Key:  make([]byte, 0),
            }
        }
        zipStruct, err = extractFiles(file)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        print(zipStruct)
        //clusterSetupZip[name].Pfx = append(clusterSetupZip[name].Pfx, zipStruct.Pfx...)
        //clusterSetupZip[name].Cert = append(clusterSetupZip[name].Cert, zipStruct.Cert...)
        //clusterSetupZip[name].Key = append(clusterSetupZip[name].Key, zipStruct.Key...)
    }

    return clusterSetupZip, nil
}

func extractFiles(file *zip.File) (*CertificateHolder, error) {
    var zipStructure CertificateHolder
    rc, err := file.Open()
    if err != nil {
        return &CertificateHolder{}, err
    }
    defer rc.Close()

    bytes, err := ioutil.ReadAll(rc)
    if err != nil {
        return &CertificateHolder{}, err
    }

    fileExtension := filepath.Ext(file.Name)
    switch fileExtension {
    case ".pfx":
        zipStructure.Pfx = bytes
    case ".crt":
        zipStructure.Cert = bytes
    case ".key":
        zipStructure.Key = bytes
    }
    return &zipStructure, nil
}
```

Comment: What's your question? Is this a question about style? Or performance? Or correctness? Or maintainability?

Comment: all of them....